# How to retrieve remote outlook contacts programmatically in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, outlook, abaddressbook

In my app i want to search into my contacts - be it for local contacts or remote contacts that can be retrieved from exchange account or some other mail accounts(just like the mail app does).

I am pretty clear about the local searching and fetching. i was looking forward if any of you brilliant guys there knew how i can proceed further in my problem.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In case of an Exchange mailbox, you can use [EWS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd877045(v=exchg.140).aspx) API (HTTP based).

Comment: Could you elaborate it a bit more?

Comment: What do you want to know? Did you look at the link in the answer? EWS is HTTP based, so if you can post an HTTP request and read the response, you will be able to use the Exchange Web Services API.

Comment: Sorry for being pushy but could you provide me with some code or some example?